# How can I install ack (ack-grep) with apt on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, 17.10

Somewhere during the upgrade to 17.04 or 17.10, the `ack-grep` package disappeared. According to `aptitude`, it was deleted and has some config files left:

```
root@example:~ # aptitude search ^ack
c   ack                         -
v   ack-grep                    -
```

Now I'd like it back, but...

```
root@example:~ # apt-get install ack-grep
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package ack-grep is a virtual package provided by:
  ack 2.14-5 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'ack-grep' has no installation candidate

root@example:~ # apt-get install ack
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package ack is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ack' has no installation candidate
```

I have enabled the "main", "restricted", "universe", and "multiverse" repositories.

I also tried installing the specific version mentioned above:

```
root@example:~ # apt-get install ack=2.14-5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Can't find a source to download version '2.14-5' of 'ack:amd64'
```

Is there anything else I can do (other than bypassing apt and installing it directly)?

Comment: It appears to have been replaced by [silversearcher-ag](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/silversearcher-ag)

Comment: ag is not a replacement for ack.  They do similar things, but one is not a replacement for the other.

Comment: See this question for information about what happened to the ack package: https://askubuntu.com/questions/972083/unable-to-find-ack-in-ubuntu-17-10-repositories